# Forcing integer overflow in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to emulate something written in Java in python.  There is a symmetric encryption algorithm in the Java part, where key generation relies on Java long integers overflowing. I now need to do this in Python to be able to decrypt there. I did not write the encryption algorithm, and I cannot change that.  This is part of the key generator function in Java:

```
long a;
long b;
...
for (...)
    ...
    a = b + ((b << 1) + (b << 4) + (b << 7) + (b << 8) + (b << 35));
```

Now when I copy this as it is to Python, I will receive massive numbers, as Python does what it is supposed to do and adds more bytes to my integer, while in Java the integers just keep overflowing and eventually a 64 bit key is returned.  This is not the entirety of the code, it is actually a loop that keeps doing this and other things to a and b, so I cannot just take the highest 64 bits or something like that and treat that as my new a.

However, I now need to emulate this behaviour in Python to get my decryption key.

How do I do this in Python? Is it even possible, or do I need to rely on a C function for this part, and do the key generation there?

Comment: Try using `numpy.int64`

Comment: `a &= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` discards all but the low 64 bits of the variable.

Comment: You can also bitwise-and (`&` operator) results with `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, but you have to be careful to do it at each point an overflow could occur.

Comment: You can use `numpy` maybe or maybe `ctypes` if `numpy` is too much for just this.

Comment: numpy.int64() worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need signed 64-bit integers here, or would unsigned 64-bit integers work?

Comment: It does not matter as it is just a bit field used for AES. Java shows numbers as signed but it does not matter what the numerical representation is as long as bits are correct. numpy.int64() seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store all of the integers in numpy arrays they will overflow (because numpy is using C for arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks. numpy.int64() seems to be working fine. I have never used numpy for anything and I wasn't aware of these structures.

Comment: Just be a bit careful with some numpy types, when combining with integers. For example, on my machine, `np.uint64(1) + 1` gives a float.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use numpy or any other external library; raw Python is powerful enough for what you're after. Although if you can express your whole algorithm in terms of vector operations, a numpy implementation will be much faster.

Just add this line after the one you showed, which gives the remainder of a modulo 2 to the power 64:

```
a = a % 2**64
```

Or you can use this line, which does bitwise AND with a number whose final 64 bits are 1s:

```
a = a & ((1 << 64) - 1)
```

These two statements are equivalent, and the performance difference is probably negligible. So I suggest choosing the one that makes most sense to you, which will depend on whether you consider it to be more of an arithmetic operation (the first one) or a bitwise operation. Obviously change 64 to 32 or whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: This assumes that the numbers are unsigned, though.

Comment: It seems possible (even likely) that the encryption algorithm is most naturally expressed in unsigned integers, but that of course implementing it in Java would require using signed integers.

Comment: This would probably work as well. I have no problem using numpy for this and it solved the problem. Signed and unsigned is not relevant here as it is in practice just a binary number used in AES encryption. It does not need a numerical representation. Java shows it as signed but it does not matter.

Comment: @tobias_k Assuming that only the bottom 64 bits ultimately matter, i.e. you don't distinguish between -1 and (2^64-1), these methods would still work.

Comment: @Hannu The source of tobias_k's worry is that in Python a negative number is in principle represented as an infinite sequence of 1 bits (in principle), not by the 64th bit like in a Java long. For example 2**64-1 is 1111...1111 (64 ones) but -1 is ...11111111 (infinitely many ones). If you only show the last 64 bits at the end of the algorithm then there's no difference, but if you show more digits or try to compare `2**61-1 == -1` then you might get results you don't want.

Comment: Luckily this does not have any subtractions, only additions and bit shifts. I guess I am safe with numpy here.